# android: Android Development

Tags: android

I have a trouble on turning from page view to the main app page. Page views are introductions for the app, I set a button on the last page of introductions. Users can touch the button and start use the app.(The screen should show main page). But I use the code in the java file (I will show code under the question). After I put the code and run it, the app can't work.(It splashed) How could I solve the problem?

The following statement is the code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(pageforintroductions.this, 
    page11_firstuserpages.class);
    startActivity(intent); }
});


Button button17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        button17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(pageforintroductions.this, page11_firstuserpages.class);
                startActivity(intent); }
        });
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you properly set an intent to go from one activity to another.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Excuse me , setOnClickListener become red. And the hint shows: Add qualified PageView to method.

Comment: id have to see more of your code. did you initialize the button in the onCreate method?

Comment: I have updated the code on my post.Please check it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(pageforintroductions.this, page11_firstuserpages.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```